# Кросс-компиляция на QtСreator компиляторами LLVM

Tags: c++, c, qtcreator, cmake, llvm

Есть cmake проект с настроенной кросс-компиляцией с тулчейном GCC. В качестве IDE используется QtСreator. Теперь хочу попробовать настроить в QtCreator сборку этого-же проекта при помощи LLVM, но как это сделать? Следую вот [этой](https://llvm.org/docs/HowToCrossCompileLLVM.html) инструкции, там написано, что надо вставлять флаги `-DCMAKE_CROSSCOMPILING=True -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=<install-dir> -DLLVM_TABLEGEN=<path-to-host-bin>/llvm-tblgen -DCLANG_TABLEGEN=<path-to-host-bin>/clang-tblgen -DLLVM_DEFAULT_TARGET_TRIPLE=arm-linux-gnueabihfDLLVM_TARGET_ARCH=ARM -DLLVM_TARGETS_TO_BUILD=ARM` но куда и как их вставлять в QtCreator?

OS: Ubuntu 20.04.1; 
Cmake: 3.19;
LLVM и Clang: 10;
Кросскомпиляция: Linux x86 -> Linux ArmA7 hf;
QtCreator: 4.14.0;

Сама библиотека Qt в проекте не используется.

Comment: приведенные вами флаги - это флаги cmake, никакого отношения к QtCreator они не имеют. Просто запустите cmake с этими параметрами и укажите директорию с CMakeLists.txt

Comment: @AndrejLevkovitch я вижу что это флаги cmake. Вопрос был в том, как мне заставить QtCreator вызывать cmake с этими флагами, и что еще нужно сделать что-бы это заработало? Мне нужно что-бы проект собирался при нажатии кнопки Build и запускался на удалённой машине при нажатии кнопки Run. Я же не буду каждый раз что-то редактируя в коде, сворачивать IDE, руками вызывать cmake, руками переносить файл на таргет-машину и т.д.

Comment: не могу не заметить, что в вопросе у вас ни слова про перенос на таргет машину. Что же касается вызова build - то вам следует понимать, что это флаги конфигурации, а не сборки. Их нужно прописать именно для фазы конфигурации и принудительно переконфигурить проект при изменении